# vb.net Code doesn't work the first time it's run, but does on subsequent runs

Tags: vb.net

After spending all night plagued with object reference not set errors. I finally managed to get some code that works. The problem is simply that I have to click the button 2x before it does:

```
    dim turl as string
    dim eles as htmlcollection

    turl = textbox1.text

    'Navigate to task page
    iexplore.Navigate(turl)

    Do
        eles = iexplore.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td")
    Loop While IsNothing(eles) or iexplore.IsBusy

    For Each he As HtmlElement In eles
        If Not IsNothing(he.InnerText) Then
            If he.InnerText.Contains("Remove") Then
                If Not IsNothing(he.NextSibling) Then
                    If Not IsNothing(he.NextSibling.InnerText) Then
                        If Not he.NextSibling.InnerText.Contains("Completed") Then
                            If Not IsNothing(he.Parent.Children.Item(3)) Then
                                MsgBox(he.Parent.Children.Item(3).InnerText)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

iexplore is a reference to a web browser control.

Is there anything that anyone can think of that I should add in order to ensure that the button only needs to be clicked once? (yes its on a single click event, the other code that gets called runs the first time without issues, it's only this section that seems to require 2 clicks).

I'd also like to note that it behaves like this every time a new url is introduced.

edited: Fixed infinite loop

Comment: Did you try debugging with break on all exceptions (even caught ones)?  There are sometimes exceptions that are caught by the debugger when they're not supposed to, it could be that there's an exception on the first run.

Comment: Also, did you step through to see if failing conditions is what causes it to not reach to `MsgBox` line?

Comment: That is problematic because I can't run the code through the debugger. The debugger doesn't have permission to access some of the files that get access when the code is run

Comment: edited the post a smidge.

Comment: You might want to look at this:   http://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2009/05/27/anti-patterns-and-worst-practices-the-arrowhead-anti-pattern/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access your page before the navigation completes, try accessing it in the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event handler.

---

Edit per request of OP about how to remove a EventHandler to prevent multiple handlers assigned to the Event. Removing a non existant handler will not cause an error.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf DocumentCompleted
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("Http:\\www.Google.com")
End Sub

Private Sub DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    RemoveHandler DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser).DocumentCompleted, AddressOf DocumentCompleted
    MsgBox("hello")
End Sub
```

Comment: My concern with this approach is that I actually load a document as soon as the program launches. The loaded document requires authentication so I force users to get that out of the way so the program can freely use the authentication token from that point forward. I do not want the code to run when that first document is loaded. It seems like this is a "do this every time a document loads" approach, which is not what I need. If it is that Im trying to access the doc too soon, I may have to throw a timer in there. Would rather not though...

Comment: You can not access something that is not physically available. You may need to put some sort of conditional there to test for first document load. Or check that you have your authorization token

Comment: Im curious, if I put the add handler line inside the button click event, it shouldn't work until the button is clicked no?

Comment: I moved it and set it up as my previous comment and it worked except it showed the msgbox 2x....

Comment: Thats correct, but you need to be careful that you do not add it multiple times. You can remove the handler either before you add it in the click event or in the document completed event.

Comment: Can you update your answer to include the syntax for adding and removing handlers? I would gladly accept it as an answer then :) Also, maybe an explanation why it's bad to have 2 of the same event handlers; for anyone who stumbles upon this in the future.

Comment: The reason that it is bad is that each one you add will run, it will not stop at 2. I am mobile, let me see if I can get something intelligible added to the answer

Comment: I added the event handler to the form's load event and created a way for the event to return a true when it is done loading, then I created a do nothing loop before my code to wait for the event to return true so that I can continue. I never had the intention to attach it to a click even /wink. It's all in the spirit of providing as much information as possible for future newbs like me :)